# Why is restatable giving a new number to restated theorems?

Tags: theorems

I used restatable in a submission to  we'll say "Conference A" with their style formatting, and it worked fine. I'll use a specific lemma as an example. In the Conference A paper, it is labeled Lemma 1 in the body, and Lemma 1 in the Appendix when I restate it to prove it. However, I just transferred the paper to "Conference B" formatting, and now it's labeled as Lemma 4.1 in the body, and Lemma B.1 in the Appendix. It's very frustrating because I didn't change anything, so it must be in the cls file or something. Here is the code in the body (section 4):

```
\begin{restatable}{lemma}{half}\label{lem:half}
... Theorem Statement...
\end{restatable}
```

And in the B section of the Appendix I just do:

```
\half*
```

It's got to be something about how Conference B numbers the theorems, because they use for instance Lemma 4.1 instead of Lemma 1, right? I don't think I'm allowed to change it per conference guidelines. Any ideas? Or other ways to do this? I don't want to have to copy all my theorems/lemmas for their proofs in the Appendix. There are many and I might need to change them slightly over time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. `*it must be in the cls file*` Yep, you are probably right.

Comment: The point of automatic numbering and cross-referencing is, *you do not need to care about it*.

Comment: Well that's annoying. I recall hearing someone talk about defining your own environment for theorems, lemmas, etc, but I'm worried that that is considered skirting the formatting that the conference calls for. I'm not sure how familiar you are with submitting to conferences, but do you think this approach to a solution might violate the conference formatting policy?

Comment: Really depends on the conference and what they expect you to offer. Most *just want* the tex source, to format it to their needs. Drop them a quick mail and ask what they want/need.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much!